# OpenCV: how to access a blue pixel only?

Tags: python, opencv, pixel

From [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#basic-ops), I found this code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy

img=cv2.imread('picture.jpg')  

# Accessing only blue pixel
blue=img[100,100,0]
print blue # it prints 157
```

Could someone explain me this line please : `blue=img[100,100,0]` ? I do not understand it because to access a pixel, we need only its x and y coordinates, so I do not understand the third coordinate here and what relation does it have with the a blue pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`img[100,100,0]` returns the blue channel value of the pixel with coordinates [100,100]

To get the whole pixel, we simply need to run this `img[100,100]` and it will give  a BGR list such as `[157, G, R]`

**Example:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
img=cv2.imread('photo.png')
px=img[300,300]
print px
blue=img[300,300,0]
print blue
```

**Ouput:**

```
[47 72 62 ]
47
```

47 is the blue channel intensity for the pixel defined by the coordinates (300,300)

This answer is given to me by the [Antti Haapala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala)

Answer (score 2):

An image in OpenCV is represented as a 3D numpy ndarray. The first two axes (X and Y) represent the pixel matrix.
The third axis (Z) contains the color channels (B,G,R). What you are doing in this line, is selecting a pixel by x, y and z coordinates. The third index (the 0) in `img[100,100,0]` is the 0'th element in the array of the pixel's color values [B,G,R], thus your blue color channel.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned,

> img[100,100,0] returns the blue channel value of the pixel with coordinates [100,100]

The first two numbers are the `[row, column]` values of the pixel location while the third is the colour value. Since in this case we have the colour value set as `0` we are accessing the blue value. If we were to change this last value from a `0` to a `1` or `2`, we would be accessing the green or red value respectively.

Example:

```
px = img[100,100] #we are accessing pixel location at [row,column]
print (px) 

#Accessing the blue, green and red intensity in the image
blue = img[100,100,0]
green = img[100,100,1]
red = img[100,100,2]

#printing intensity 
print (blue) 
print (green)
print (red)
```

Output:

```
[57 63 68]
57
63
68
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers did not dive deep enough. If you want to understand why does img[100, 100, 0] return blue, we have to check img object itself.

img object is expressed as a ndarray. To make it clear, just crop a 5x5 pixels image and check what it is actually.

```
>>>img.shape
(5, 5, 3)

>>>img
array([[[ 73, 121, 129],
    [ 67, 111, 122],
    [ 62,  97, 111],
    [ 72, 105, 121],
    [ 79, 115, 128]],

   [[ 72, 119, 134],
    [ 73, 119, 134],
    [ 70, 109, 124],
    [ 66, 104, 118],
    [ 63, 107, 118]],

   [[ 80, 125, 143],
    [ 66, 114, 132],
    [ 68, 111, 128],
    [ 63, 103, 117],
    [ 55,  99, 110]],

   [[104, 142, 164],
    [ 76, 122, 137],
    [ 77, 121, 138],
    [ 70, 109, 124],
    [ 57,  97, 109]],

   [[ 80, 117, 135],
    [ 66, 110, 124],
    [ 71, 114, 129],
    [ 86, 123, 137],
    [ 77, 115, 126]]], dtype=uint8)

>>> img[2, 2, 0]
68
```

Answer (score -3):

It looks like the `[100,100,0]` aren't pixel coordinates but BGR color  coordinates.

`[100, 100, 0]` in BGR translates to `#006464` in hex, which is indeed blue.

Comment: If I may ask (even if may be I should post this as a different question): why the print (on the link I gave via my question) outputs 157 ? I mean, what does it represent ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that number represents the amount of pixels in the image that match those BGR color coordinates.

Comment: THAT is the value of the blue channel on the pixel at [100,100]. But I guess you already found out.